# How would I go about doing this - process tree maybe?

Tags: java

I am not asking for the program to be written for me. I am just having a hard time figuring out the process I should take to do the following -

Create ArrayLists for 3 categories. Prompt the user to specify which array to populate or to quit entries. If the user doesn't quit, the program will accept data into the area that the user had selected.  When the user quits, a report will show on the screen showing the sorted data of the 3 categories.

I would LOVE if someone would say something like -
1. create blah
2. create blah #2
3. create blah 3
4.  setup an if/else statement that does blah.
...

I have a few weeks to do this program and want to tackle it on my own.  I just need a step-by-step idea of how to go about doing this program.  I am just feeling overwhelmed right now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a step-by-step for a command-line program:

1. Create some static variables of your main class for the array lists.
2. In the main method:

   1. Initialize the array lists to be empty.
   2. Ask the user whether they should quit, or add to array list 1, or 2, or 3.
   3. If the user decides to quit, quit.
   4. If the user decides to add to an array list, declare a variable for the appropriate array list.
   5. Use if/else statements to assign the variable to the appropriate array list.
   6. Ask the user for content.
   7. For each new item, add it to the array list.
   8. When the user is done with the input, invoke `Collections.sort` on the array list.
   9. Display the array list to the user.
   10. Go to step 2.

Comment: Thank you!  As you can tell, I want to do this on my own if at all possible.

Comment: @HectorRamos There's nothing wrong with copying a working model of I/O, say, without understanding it in complete detail. Reuse is an important value in programming. But the logic is yours to ace!

Answer (score 0):

1. start by creating classes for 3 categories you wish to have lists for and with constructors.
2. Then read inputs from file or command line.
3. Create instances of each class and populate your arraylists.
4. have a while loop which exists when user enters q or quit or the literal you want to use to quit.
5. Print your output
6. TEST if it works fine.

I think its enough for you to start with.